# How to stream video from IP Camera Planet HM126 to a webpage

Tags: video, streaming, camera, mjpeg

Unfortunately, I'm not able to find how I should set up this specific model of Planet IP camera to stream its video somewhere. (Is it even possible?)

Finally I'd like to put that stream into my webpage, but that's the part I can handle on my own.

I tried webpages like http://forum.synology.com/wiki/index.php/User_Reported_Compatible_IP_Cameras but nothing worked. Any other suggestions?

Comment: You need to first give your IP camera a static or reserved IP in your LAN. Next you need to forward the relevat ports from your router to your IP camera -> finally you need to write your webpage and put your camera streaming player and point it to your home IP. Be careful, though, if your home IP changes ((A)DSL can change quite frequently) then you'll have to update your webpage with the new IP.

Comment: I've got it all, but I don't know URL of the stream and I'm not able find out which URL is it.

Comment: What's the exact make and model of your camera?

Comment: Planet HM216 as title says :)

Comment: I'm trying to Google the two camera versions you've provided... Title says "HM126", comment says "HM216"... I can't find any information or manuals for your product... can you add this?

Comment: Sorry Chris, 216 was a typo, that should be this one - http://www.amazon.com/Planet-ICA-HM126-H-264-Full-Camera/dp/B00TSQWD66

Answer (score 0):

Your camera supports RTSP and MJPEG streaming formats so you have various options available...

There are ActiveX plugins that will allow you to view an RTSP stream - this needs to be installed on whoever views your website - can be quite messy.

Alternatively, your camera supporting MJPEG, is quite trivial and a number of JavaScript libraries and solutions have been written where you simply locate the streaming URL (in .mjpeg format) and plug it into your HTML/JavaScript code. An example: http://141.89.114.98/demo/edu640x480v.html